# PHP cafile working, capath not (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, ssl

I have an issue installing/using a self-signed certificate in PHP. (The background is: I want to use a private composer repository)

I installed the certificate in /etc/ssl/certs using sudo update-ca-certificates. The certificate is now installed correctly.

If I configure the certificate as cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem everything works as expected.

Now I thought it must be possible to use capath instead of cafile. So I configured capath=/etc/ssl/certs and cafile=
This configuration is NOT working, so the mycert.pem is not found?!

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was within the certificate itself. It had an invalid CR.

If I specified the certificate directly there is no issue with it, but if it is used as part of the certs folder I had to remove ^M